# Find best match from regex capture group

Tags: .net, regex

I'd like to find the best match with a given regex-capturegroup.
Example:

Regex: (AB|ABC)

Sample: ABCDEF

Result: AB

But I'd like to find ABC (the best fit from the option-list).

How can this be done? (except of exchanging the both alternatives in the group)?

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: I doubt you can do such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying your best matches in order (e.g., longest strings first).  Many RE engines prefer left-most first in their "eager evaluation" mode.  Only POSIX REs mandate that the longest matching alternate be returned:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: Good advice, +1. I'd like to add that I prefer the behavior of non-POSIX regex engines because it allows me to determine myself what I consider the "best" match - it doesn't always have to be the longest one. Size doesn't...you know...

Comment: ;-) Yes, you're right.
I'll do the bestmatch-finding via the order in the capturegroup.